# Como reescribir esta funcion de Jquery a Vue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuex

Tengo esta función que deshabilita un input luego de haber ingresado un codigo y tambien le da funcionalidad a un boton para cambiar ese estado del input si es necesario cambiar el codigo ingresado:

```
var GoogleTagManagerApplication = function(options) {
    var self = this;

    this.validationTimer = null;

    this.ELEMENTS = {
        META_INPUT : '#googleTagManagerInput',
        EDIT_GTM_CODE : '#changeGTMCode'
    };

    this.init = function() {
        self.initEventHandlers();
    };

    this.initEventHandlers = function() {
        $(window).on('blur', self.ELEMENTS.META_INPUT, self.notifyUpdate);
        $(window).on('focus', self.ELEMENTS.META_INPUT, function() { $(this).select(); });
        $(window).on('click', self.ELEMENTS.EDIT_GTM_CODE, self.enableTextArea)

        self.validationTimer = new KeyboardTimer({
            target : self.ELEMENTS.META_INPUT,
            callback : self.notifyUpdate
        });
    };

    this.enableTextArea = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(self.ELEMENTS.META_INPUT).prop('disabled', false);
        $(self.ELEMENTS.META_INPUT).focus();
    };
```

La cual debo transformar para poder incluirla en un archivo que tengo de Vue. como podria hacer?

Tengo mayores datos si con esto no es suficiente.

agrego imagenes para que vean ejemplo del funcionamiento que busco.

1-Input vacio habilitado para ingresar un codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2 - Ingreso un codigo valido y guardo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3 - Se deshabilita para edicion el input

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4 - Y al hacer click en el boton cambiar, se vuelve a habilitar el input para poder cambiar el codigo ingresado.

Añado la parte del input de mi componente en VUE:

```
<div v-if="googleTagManagerCode">
                  <b-paragraph
                    class="flLeft marginElement">
                    {{i18nTexts.insertedCode}}: {{googleTagManagerCode}}
                  </b-paragraph>
                  <b-link class="linkForm"
                    id="changeGTMCode"
                    @click="isDisabled=true"
                    :disabled="isDisabled">
                    {{i18nTexts.inputChange}}
                  </b-link>
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                  <b-paragraph
                    class="flLeft marginElement">
                    {{i18nTexts.codeTitle}}
                  </b-paragraph>
                  <b-link class="linkForm"
                    @click="clickcodeObtein">
                    {{i18nTexts.linkForm}}
                  </b-link>
                </div>
              <div v-if="googleTagManagerCode">
                <b-input
                  type="text"
                  :disabled="isDisabled"
                  v-show="TagCode"
                />
              </div>
              <div v-else>
                <b-input
                  type="text"
                  id="googleTagManagerInput"
                  :value="googleTagManagerCode"
                  :maxlength="12"
                  placeholder="GTM-XXXXXX"
                  @change="updatetagmanagercode"
                />
              </div>
```

en el componente está el titulo y el input tal cual el de las imagenes adjuntas.

les comparto los textos de lo que pueden encontrar en el componente para mayor claridad.

```
codeTitle: this.translateText('Código de Google Tag Manager'),
linkForm: this.translateText('¿Cómo obtener el código?'),
insertedCode: this.translateText('Tu código de Google Tag Manager es'),
inputChange: this.translateText('Cambiar')
```

Agrego la propiedad computada:

```
isDisabled () {
        return !this.TagCode;
      }
```

Comment: Puedes incluirlo en el componente de Vue en la parte <script> y lo puedes usar la función GoogleTagManagerApplication dentro de tu código.

Comment: Explica con un ejemplo lo que necesitas hacer. Se mas claro. Todo lo que decis, parece requerir solo de una bandera en tu vue que diga que activar o desactivar.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta como siempre @gbianchi ahi hice las ediciones para que sea mas claro lo que necesito.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta como siempre @YohanLaborda ahi hice las ediciones para que sea mas claro lo que necesito.

Comment: Podrias mostrar como es tu componente Vue?

Comment: Mostrado @gbianchi

Comment: Creo que a mi respuesta le falta un pedazo.. pero no termino de entender todo lo que tiene que hacer tu codigo. De ser asi, vamos comentandola asi agregamos lo que falta

Comment: Ahora que miro bien tu variable computada, no tiene ningun sentido.. no computa nada...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar una bandera en tu data que mantenga el estado del control que queres habilitar/deshabilitar y según la selección del usuario cambiar esa bandera:

En el b-input, podes usar la propiedad disable de la siguiente forma:

```
<b-input
    ...
    :disabled="band"
/>
```

Y en tu data tener algo asi:

```
data () {
    return {
        band: false
            }
        }
```

De esa forma, cambiando esa bandera entre true y false podes habilitar o deshabilitar el input.

Comment: Perfecto, esto me sirve. Y lo que me resta es como al hacer click en el boton cambie el inpút a enable?

Comment: Lo mismo.. si cambias la bandera en el boton, va a cambiar el estado.. @NicolasSeguro