# Inhabilitar input al guardar y habilitar con boton en Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, vue.js, vuex

Tengo un componente que contiene un input donde se ingresa un codigo, al validar el codigo muestra un texto de que mi "Mi codigo es: GTM-XXXX" y se habilita el boton "guardar" al guardar el codigo queda inyectado en el input.

Lo que necesito es:

- Que ese texto "Mi codigo es: GTM-XXXX" se habilite recien al guardar, no al momento de haber ingresado un codigo en el input.
- Que el input quede deshabilitado mostrando el codigo antes ingresado, y al tocar el boton "cambiar" se habilite para poder editar en el input.

Mi componente:

```
 <template>
  <b-page-content>
    <div slot="breadcrumb" fluid>
      <b-breadcrumb
        :items="breadcrumbPath"
        first-item-color="orange"
        >
      <div class="guardarBt headerRegion">
        <b-button
          class="btn-cancel marginRight5"
          @click="clickBtnCancel">
          {{ i18nTexts.btnCancel }}
        </b-button>
          <b-button
            class="btn-confirm marginRight5"
            @click="confirm"
            :disabled="!valid"
            >
            {{ i18nTexts.btnConfirm }}
          </b-button>
          </div>
            </b-breadcrumb>
              </div>
                <content-wrapper>
                  <b-grid
                    :section-title="i18nTexts.tagmanagerTitle"
                    :summary="i18nTexts.tagmanagerDescription">
                  <div slot="right-slot">
                    <b-box>
                    <b-col class="d-none d-lg-block">
                      <img :src="LogoTag"/>
                    </b-col>
                  <div v-if="lastGoogleTagManagerCode">
                  <b-paragraph
                    class="flLeft marginElement">
                    {{i18nTexts.insertedCode}}: {{googleTagManagerCode}}
                  </b-paragraph>
                  <b-link class="linkForm"
                    @click="inputChange"
                    >
                    {{i18nTexts.inputChange}}
                  </b-link>
                  </div>
                  <div v-else>
                  <b-paragraph
                    class="flLeft marginElement">
                    {{i18nTexts.codeTitle}}
                  </b-paragraph>
                  <b-link class="linkForm"
                    @click="clickcodeObtein">
                    {{i18nTexts.linkForm}}
                  </b-link>
                </div>
                <div>
                <b-input
                  type="text"
                  :value="lastGoogleTagManagerCode"
                  :maxlength="12"
                  placeholder="GTM-XXXXXX"
                  @change="updatetagmanagercode"
                />
              </div>
          </b-box>
        </div>
      </b-grid>
    </content-wrapper>
  </b-page-content>
</template>
```

y aca mi data:

```
data () {
    return {
        codeObtein: 'https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/tag-manager/',
        text:'',
        LogoTag,
        Cancel: '/marketing/applications',
        googleTagManagerCode: null,
        lastGoogleTagManagerCode: null,
        valid: false
      }
  },
```

y mis methods:

```
methods: {
      clickcodeObtein() {
        window.open(this.codeObtein, '_blank').focus()
      },
      clickBtnCancel() {
        window.location.href = '/marketing/applications'
      },
      async confirm() {
        helperModal.showWindowContentLoading()
        let response = await ApiService.post('/config/updateExtraConfiguration', {
          google_tag_manager_code: this.lastGoogleTagManagerCode
        });

        if (response.success) {
          this.messageManager.showSuccessMessage(this.translateText('Se han guardado correctamente los cambios.'))
          helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
          window.location.href = '/marketing/applications'
        } else {
          this.messageManager.showErrorMessage(this.translateText('No se han podido guardar los cambios. Intenta nuevamente.'))
          helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
        }
      },
      updatetagmanagercode(value) {
        this.lastGoogleTagManagerCode = value
        var GTMCodeRegex = /^(GTM-[A-Z0-9]+)$/i

        if ((value != '' && !GTMCodeRegex.test(value)) || (value == '')) {
          this.valid = false
          this.messageManager.showErrorMessage(this.translateText('El código ingresado no es válido'))
        } else {
          this.valid = true

        }

      },
      async loadGoogleTagManagerCode() {
        let response = await ApiService.get('/config/company/google_tag_manager_code', {});
        if (!response.success) {
          this.messageManager.showErrorMessage(this.translateText(response.message))
        } else {
          helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
        }
        this.lastGoogleTagManagerCode = response.data.google_tag_manager_code;
        this.googleTagManagerCode = response.data.google_tag_manager_code

        return response
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.loadGoogleTagManagerCode()
    },
    metaInfo() {
      return {
        title: this.pageName
      }
    }
  }
```

Entiendo que deberia funcionar de esta manera pero no se traducirlo al codigo en vue:

1) "Modo edicion" que seria un boolean
por defecto (cuando no tenes un codigo guardado) ese valor es true
y cuando tenes un valor guardado, en false (lo tendrias que setear cuando finaliza la busqueda del codigo en el servidor)
entonces, si el valor ese es true
lo que vas a hacer es dejar el input modificable
y si es false, disabled
entonces en caso que tengas un codigo guardado, el valor seria false. Y lo que haria el link de "modificar" seria cambiarlo a true
habilitando asi el input

2) El hecho de mostrar "tu codigo es GTM-XXXX..." o "ingresa tu codigo de google" deberia basarse en si ya tengo guardado un valor o no
entonces, tambien deberia mostrar uno u otro de acuerdo al analisis de la respuesta del server

Comment: En que se diferencia este problema planteado aca, del problema que planteaste aca? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/270935/324

Comment: en que ahora necesito que funcione al momento de haber guardado, no al ingresar un codigo en el input @gbianchi

Comment: @gbianchi agregué texto explicando un poco mejor para ser mas claro

Comment: No entiendo cual es la diferencia...

Comment: Me parece que tenes un problema en entender como funciona vue. Las variables son todas reactivas. con lo cual generar una bandera es trivial y es igual a tu pregunta anterior. Activar o desactivar controles es igual, solo cambias el momento dependendiendo el evento que quieras usar (en este caso el click del boton). Pasate por el [chat] y lo hablamos.